# Solution to 4x4 system of linear ODEs: what do the eigenvectors and eigenvalues represent and the solution to the ODE?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following system of homogeneous linear differential equations that I wish to solve:
$$
\textbf{M}\ddot{\textbf{q}} + \textbf{G}\dot{\textbf{q}} + \textbf{D}\dot{\textbf{q}} + \textbf{K}\textbf{q} =  \textbf{0}
$$

In this case the vector $\textbf{q}$ is a $\boldsymbol{4 \times 1}$ vector of the system states. Let's say $\textbf{q} = \begin{bmatrix} q_{1} & q_{2} & q_{3} & q_{4} \end{bmatrix}^\top$.

The matrices involved are as follows:
$$
\textbf{M} =
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & m_{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & m_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\textbf{D} =
\begin{bmatrix}
d_{11} & d_{12}  & 0   & 0    \\
d_{21} & d_{22} & 0   & 0    \\
0   & 0   & d_{33} & d_{34} \\
0   & 0   & d_{43} & d_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\textbf{K} =
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11} & k_{12}  & 0   & 0    \\
k_{21} & k_{22} & 0   & 0    \\
0   & 0   & k_{33} & k_{34} \\
0   & 0   & k_{43} & k_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\textbf{G} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 0   & g_{1}  & 0 \\
0  & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
g_{2}  & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By introducing the state vector $ \textbf{x(t)} = \pmatrix{\textbf{q(t)} \\ \dot{\textbf{q(t)}}}$, the system is transformed into the state space form $ \dot{\textbf{x(t)}} = \textbf{A}\textbf{x(t)} + \textbf{B}\textbf{u(t)}$.

In this case, I end up with the $\textbf{A}$ matrix:
$$ \textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{0} & \textbf{I} \\
-\textbf{M}^{-1}[\textbf{K} + \textbf{D}] & -\textbf{M}^{-1}\textbf{G} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can then solve for the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$. I just wanted to ask, what do these eigenvectors and eigenvalues represent? And how do they relate to the individual state variables $\textbf{q} = \begin{bmatrix} q_{1} & q_{2} & q_{3} & q_{4} \end{bmatrix}^\top$?

I am a bit confused, especially considering that this is a coupled system of ODEs. I want to understand how the different parameters involved affect the dynamics of the system.

Comment: What’s the structure of the matrix $K$?

Comment: My apologies, I made a typo. K and D are block diagonal matrices and M is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: $G$ and $D$ can be combined, right? Both are factor for $\dot{q}$, unless there is a typo.

Comment: Hello John, yes they can